# Azure func start failing on M1 Mac with Core Tools 4.0.5030

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, apple-silicon, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to run `func host start` with the default azure HTTP function for python on my M1 Mac but keep getting the following error:

```
 *  Executing task: . .venv/bin/activate && func host start 

Found Python version 3.9.16 (python3).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5030 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.15.2.20177

[2023-03-06T12:16:54.298Z] Failed to initialize worker provider for: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.298Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.776Z] Failed to initialize worker provider for: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.776Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.931Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'a05c2dec-c700-4cb8-a8b0-e66cf535215d'.
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.931Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find functions with language [python].
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.938Z] Failed to stop host instance '53731cda-f5d1-461a-b6b9-f627368ea3e0'.
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.938Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The host has not yet started.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.957Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '057668d3-eee0-4a79-bf04-7a09d4bf398b'.
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.957Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection: Cannot access a disposed object.
[2023-03-06T12:16:54.957Z] Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
```

I've tried all the advice in this thread on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1050) (like installing azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.4483 with npm and copying _cython) and I've tried different python versions (3.8, 3.9, 3.10 installed with brew and with conda) but I can't resolve the issue.

Comment: Try checking by Activating the virtual environment 1st and then run the function command.

Comment: Thanks, Hari, I tried but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It's difficult getting it running on an M1 right now. Another workaround for now is using Github Codespaces with a Dev Container. You can see my Dev Container here that setups the emulator: https://github.com/pamelafox/fastapi-on-azure-functions (see .devcontainer folder)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using the attached debugger in VsCode:

create a MakeFile:

```
FUNC_VERSION = $(shell func --version)
FUNC_PATH = $(shell realpath $$(which func))
FUNC_OSX_WORKER_PATH = $(dir $(FUNC_PATH))workers/python/3.10/OSX
FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON = $(dir $(FUNC_PATH))workers/python/worker.config.json
FUNC_OSX_WORKER_X64 = $(FUNC_OSX_WORKER_PATH)/X64
FUNC_OSX_WORKER_ARM64 = $(FUNC_OSX_WORKER_PATH)/Arm64
.PHONY: $(FUNC_OSX_WORKER_ARM64)
$(FUNC_OSX_WORKER_ARM64):
    cp -r $(FUNC_OSX_WORKER_PATH)/X64 $(FUNC_OSX_WORKER_PATH)/Arm64
    pip install grpcio --upgrade --target $@

.PHONY: $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON)
$(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON): 
    cp $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON) $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON).bak
    cat $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON) \
        | jq '.description.supportedArchitectures |= .+ ["Arm64"]' \
        > $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON).tmp
    mv $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON).tmp $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON)

.PHONY: install_func_arm64_worker
install_func_arm64_worker: $(FUNC_OSX_WORKER_ARM64) $(FUNC_WORKER_CONFIG_JSON)
```

run the following:

`brew install jq`

`make install_func_arm64_worker`

Finally Start the debugger: "Attach to Python Functions"

original sources:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/915#issuecomment-1495041653